# Using factory when loading from file

Tags: c++, design-patterns, factory

I'm relativity new to C++ , though I do have a little experience in java.
Trying to approach to following problem ;(this is part of a bigger task from my university)

```
class myCustomer :public Customer {/.../}
class myFlight:public Flight {/.../}
class myEmployee :public Employee {/.../}
class myPlane :public Plane {/.../}
```

So Customer is an interface , and myCustomer is a derived class with the implementation ,same goes for the rest .(i have to use it that way)

Followed by this (sort-of) an API for a flight company data base ;

```
class MyImplementation{
   //I want to link id's to an object so i can call object pointer using a given id
   map <string,myCustomer*> customers_map;
   map <string,myEmployee*> employees_map;
   map <string,myReservation*> reservations_map;
   map <string,myPlane*> planes_map;
   map <string,myFlight*> flights_map;
...
   //must implement this function
   virtual Customer* addCustomer(string full_name, int priority){
    if(!customers_loaded){
        load_customers();
    }
    auto curr_customer = new myCustomer(id,full_name,priority);
    customers_map.insert(pair<string,myCustomer*>(id,curr_customer));
    }



    void load_customers(){
        vector<string> parameters;
        string line;
        fstream customers_file;
        customers_file.open(CUSTOMER_INFO_PATH,fstream::out);
        //check if null is returned
        if (!customers_file.is_open()) {
            throw "Error:cannot open employees file";
        }
        //iterate over lines
        while(getline(customers_file,line)){
            //just a function to split a line from file to a vector               
            parameters=splitLine(line,SPLITTER);
            try{
                customer_from_string(parameters);
            }catch(...){
                //could not load current object 
                cout << "Could not load customer "<< parameters[0] <<
                "(line number:"<< lineNumber << ")" <<endl;
                continue;
            }
        }
        customers_file.close();
    }


    void customer_from_string(vector<string> parameters){
        string id = parameters[0];
        string name = parameters[1];
        int priority = stoi(parameters [2];
        auto curr_customer = new myCustomer(id,name,priority);
        customers_map.insert(pair<string,myCustomer*>(id,curr_customer));
    }


    void employee_from_string(vector<string>& parameters,
                                map<string, string>& toLink) {
        //get parameters
        string employee_id = parameters[0];
        Jobs job = string_to_job(parameters[1]);
        int seniority = stoi(parameters[2]);
        int year = stoi(parameters[3]);
        string employer_id = parameters[4];
        //check if employee_id is legal
        if (employer_id.empty()) {
            throw "Employer ID cannot be an empty argument";
        }
        auto curr_employee = new myEmployee(employee_id, job, seniority,year);
    //add to employee map
    employees_map.insert(pair<string, myEmployee *>(employee_id, curr_employee));


    }
        /** more code**/
```

So Im trying to read parameters from a text file , and create the specified objects using matching functions like customer_from_string,employee_from_string  and i have to do it for the other classes (Planes , Reservations , Flights ...) 
each has its own constructor with different number of parameters.
Only connection between those classes is they all implement an ID interface that has a function :

```
virtual string getID() = 0;
```

Trying to avoid the following code duplication (So i won't create load function for each object ):

```
void load_employees() {
    /** same code as load_customers**/
    //iterate over lines
    while (getline(employees_file, line)) {
        //as before
        parameters = splitLine(line, SPLITTER);
        try {
            /*the only change - it has different implementation than customer_from_string*/
            employee_from_string(parameters); 
        } catch (...) {
            /** print error **/
        }
    }
    /** as before **/ 
}
```

I understand i need to approach this using a factory design pattern.(Since i need to dynamically create the objects listed in the text file,loading them to the data base each time i open the program)
So i thought about implementing the following :

```
class Factory {
virtual void create(vector<string>& parameters,
                    map<string,Factory*>&id_map,/*..more parameters*/)=0;
 }
```

and let the load method decide which object to create (maybe send a char as identifier) , using the create method above,
Let each class Implement the factory interface and than using the create function, like the following :

```
//Implementation for customer
    void create(vector<string>& parameters,map<Factory *, string>&
                 toLink,map<string,Factory*>& id_map){
        string id = parameters[0];
         string name = parameters[1];
         int priority = stoi(parameters [parameters.size()-1]);
         auto curr_customer = new myCustomer(id,name,priority);
         id_map.insert(pair<string,Factory *>(id,curr_customer));
    }
```

So i think i need to change the maps to

```
 map <string,Factory *> objectName_map;
```

Now im kinda stuck since the map holdes A pointer to a factory object , and I want to use the maps id's to do the following :

```
virtual Customer* getCustomer(string id){   //must implement this function
    if(!customers_loaded){
        load('Customers');
    }
    return customers_map.find(id)->second;
}
```

And i cannot call any inner functions for each object ,after , lets say :

```
void setEmployer(Employee* employer){//...//}
```

Since the maps are holding a Factory* .
I tried to keep the maps as they are but couldnt use them in a create function since it cannot convert a myCustomer* object to Factory* . 
Im kinda lost , tried to find solutions online but had no luck , though i feel im implementing this  wrong.
Thanks in advance for any help with this!

*Edited post to make the problem clearer

Comment: Not sure what's the problem with your implementation `MyImplementation`? What are the 6 other implementations? Different classes than customer/employer? Or different implementations?

Comment: Just some other classes for the data base i want to use (Planes, Flights,Reservations , Plane models ) . I want to implement the load and create functions so i can read parameters from the file and create the specifeied object.I'll edit to clarify.

Comment: Don't use raw pointers in map, use smart pointers (in many aspect same idea as java reference) I.e. `std::map<string, std::shared_ptr<Factory> >`. And `std::make_shared( id,full_name,priority );` can be used to construct the Factory. Then `customers_map.find(id)->second->create(...)` can be used to construct your customer instance.

Comment: You still need to create the API that returns each of the classes interfaces, you still have to write a proper API for each class.

Comment: Victor Gubin- i havent used smart pointers so i'll have to read about it and try your solution , though i didnt really understand where to use your exmaple .
@Matthieu Brucher  Are you referring to the implementation of creating the given object from the string ? if so , i know that , only trying to avoid duplicating the load ()function for each parameter so it will be used once for each one.
Ive re-edited my post , sorry if i wasnt clear with my questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, what you actually need is a "factory" template:

```
template<typename T>
pair<string, shared_ptr<T>>
from_string_vector(const vector<string>& parameters);
```

with explicit specializations like:

```
template<>
pair<string, shared_ptr<myCustomer>>
from_string_vector(const vector<string>& parameters) {
    string id = parameters[0];
    string name = parameters[1];
    int priority = stoi(parameters [2]);
    return make_pair(id, make_shared<myCustomer>(
         id, name, priority));
}
```

and the generic function like:

```
template<typename T>
void load_database(map<string, shared_ptr<T>>& objectMap,
                   const string& filename) {
    vector<string> parameters;
    string line;
    ifstream file(filename);
    while (getline(file, line)) {
        parameters = splitLine(line, SPLITTER);
        objectMap.insert(from_string_vector<T>(parameters));
    }
}
```

and then call this function 6 times for all your maps and filenames?

Comment: Umm not so much since i still need to create new (dynamic )instances of each class , passing different number of parameters to each constructor.
Maybe i didn't understand the solution all the way ?

Comment: That's the C++ way of doing what you want to do. `make_shared<myCustomer>(args...)` creates a shared pointer initialized by `new myCustomer(args...)`.
As you have no common base class between `myCustomer`, `myEmployee` etc., you should use C++ templates to write generic code for them - and you are already doing that when you are putting them into their corresponding maps.

Comment: Oh yes ! that is awesome , thank you very much for your effort !